# What is Probability Fusion on this figure?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, probability

I'm reading the paper [Few-Shot Semantic Segmentation with Prototype Learning](http://bmvc2018.org/contents/papers/0255.pdf).

I have tried to reach the authors, but they don't answer my emails, so I have decided to ask my question here because I haven't found the answer by myself.

On page 5 of that article you will find the following figure:

[image]

I think I understand everything except "Probability Fusion" (and either Image-wise NN Classifier, but this is another story). I have double check, and more, the article and I haven't found any reference to what it is, so I think it is a known network.

Could you please tell me what is "Probability Fusion"?

Comment: do you understand "prototype fusion" mentioned?

Comment: @NikosM. No, I don't understand it. Thanks.